# SVG shape-rendering on iOS

Tags: svg, mobile-safari, antialiasing

I've run into troubles with shape-rendering on iOS.

This is how my SVG should looks like (PC, shape-rendering: crispEdges): [image: Chrome 21, shape-rendering: crispEdges]

This is how it looks on iOS:
[image: Safari, iOS 5.1.1, shape-rendering: crispEdges]

It's going better if I change "crispEdges" to "crisp-edges", but still has some blur:
[image: Safari, iOS 5.1.1, shape-rendering: crisp-edges]

Any suggestions on how to get my SVG display really crisp without any antialiasing?

Comment: I dunno if it's just me, but I can't really see a difference. In what situation does this really effect your end UI?

Comment: First variant on iOS (crispEdges) is not suitable, because the edges of the rectangles are merged, you see it? But you're right, the second option with "crisp-edges" looks much better. There is a matter of principle - to understand why anti-aliasing is not turned off on Safari mobile.

Comment: crisp-edges is not a valid value for shape-rendering so it ought to make it go back to the default which is auto.

Comment: You could try moving the horizontal lines 0.5 of a pixel in the y direction in case the implementation is similar to cairo, see http://cairographics.org/FAQ/#sharp_lines

Comment: Yes, I know. It was just a guess, inspired by very old SVG specification: http://www.w3.org/1999/06/25/WD-SVG-19990625/render.html. And thanks for the link, I'll check it out.

Comment: You might want to try with `stroke-width: 0.5` and `shape-rendering: crispEdges`, this should round up to a nice solid border on all platforms.